# Crontab hanging on pipeline, scope, or poor syntax

Tags: bash, awk, cron, pipeline

I have a shell script which works fine as my user and works about halfway in crontab.  It only finishes the rm line, however, and hangs on the awk line:

```
#!/bin/bash

get_listeners.pl > temp.txt
#accesses my icecast admin page and puts some useful metrics in temp.txt

date +\%s > unpaired.txt
grep "Current Listeners" temp.txt | sed 's/[^0-9]//g' >> unpaired.txt
#first line of unpaired.txt is time, second line is number of listeners

sed '$!N;s/\n/ /' unpaired.txt >> data.dat
#combine the two lines and append it to the data file

rm unpaired.txt
#tidy up

A=$(($(date +\%s) - 86400)) | awk -v a=$1 '{if ($1 >= a) print $1,$2}' data.dat > data2.dat
#get variable of 24 hours ago; only copy lines from last 24 hours to new file

gnuplot < demo.plt
#make plot from data in new file
```

All paths are explicit in the crontab; I've just removed them here to keep it concise.

All files are set to 777 and data.dat builds up steadily (job runs once per minute) but never migrates data over to the second file in that awk line.  If anyone can point out what looks wrong with the awk line, I'm near positive that's where it's messing up.  Can variables not be pipelined in cron?  Thank you.

Comment: The `awk` line does not really make sense.  Why the pipe?  Do you want `awk` to read the pipeline, or read `data.dat`, or maybe both?
To read the pipeline, then you must write something into it.  `A=$(($(date +\%s) - 86400))` does not write anything into the pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*#get variable of 24 hours ago; only copy lines from last 24 hours to new file*

Judging from the comment, you probably want to do this:

```
A=$(($(date +\%s) - 86400))
awk -v a="$A" '$1 >= a{print $1,$2}' data.dat > data2.dat
```